# R gsub doesn't work with apply

Tags: r, error-handling, apply, sapply

I have the following line of code which takes all string after the "_" character:

```
gsub(" ","",unlist(strsplit(dtt$id,"[,_]")))[2]
```

and it works fine.However, when I try to put it into an apply function in order to do the same to all of the id's in the dtt table, I'm getting the follwing error:

```
apply(dtt,1,gsub(" ","",unlist(strsplit(dtt$id,"[,_]")))[2])
```

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir)

dtt:

id grade

1_Tim 89

2_Jack 100

3_Jeff 55

Comment: This has nothing to do with `gsub`; you're not using `apply` correctly. The third `FUN` argument of `apply` needs to be a `function` that is applied to one of the `MARGIN`s of your `data.frame`. If you provide some sample data it's easier to give an example.

Comment: Ain't gsub a function? I add an example of the dtt table in the original post.

Comment: Yes `gsub` is a function; but `FUN` needs to be a function of your corresponding `MARGIN`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
# Sample data
dtt <- read.table(text =
    "id grade
1_Tim 89
2_Jack 100
3_Jeff 55", header = T)

apply(dtt, 1, function(x) gsub(" ","", unlist(strsplit(x, "[,_]")))[2])
#[1] "Tim"  "Jack" "Jeff"
```

There is actually no need for `apply` here. You can just do:

```
gsub("\\d+_", "", dtt$id)
#[1] "Tim"  "Jack" "Jeff"
```

Or if you want to clean-up `id` entries in your `dtt`:

```
transform(dtt, id = gsub("\\d+_", "", id));
#    id grade
#1  Tim    89
#2 Jack   100
#3 Jeff    55
```

Comment: Indeed it worked! As for the apply - it seems strange to me that I need to state a function right before writing it in the same line. Wonder what is the logic behind it?

Comment: @Mark2Bra Generally there is nothing strange about it; `FUN` is a function of the `MARGIN`. So you define a function that takes a row (`MARGIN=1`) or column vector (`MARGIN=2`) as an argument. In your case and as I demonstrate, using `apply` is actually not necessary: `gsub` is already vectorised, so you can simply pass a column vector as the `x` argument.